# Is our subfloor dry enough to lay hardwood flooring on?

Tags: subfloor, hardwood-floor, moisture

we live in a coastal town in the NE and we are getting ready to lay hardwood floors. Some rooms, the lauan was not in good shape due to pulling up prior floor, so we pulled that up, but other rooms, like the kitchen and hallway, the lauan was fine from pulling up the previous floor. The fridge and the sink area show signs of old water damage on the lauan, but a mold inspector said it's definitely just old water damage and not mold.

While in the kitchen and the hallway, moisture meter is reading around 14% pretty standardly with some other days have random spots reading in-between 14%-16%, but majority of spots at 14%. The hallway does connect to the kitchen, but it goes pretty far down (at least 21 feet away from kitchen).

The meter reads the same at the edge to edge of kitchen and entire hallway from end to end.

The lauan in the dinning room that connects to the kitchen is ripped up to the chipboard. The chipboard moistsure reads at 6%. We also took up some of the lauan at the far end of the hallway and made sure the lauan on top, prior to ripping up, was at the 14% mark. Took our a square and the chipboard underneath is at 6%. Lauan all around the chipboard reads 14% moisture and chipboard at the 6%.
Same in the kitchen.

We've had a dehumidifier going and that's helped keep the lauan more consistently at 14% in all areas.

My main question is,  does this lauan need to come up? Or would a moisture barrier being put down prior to the hardwood floors being laid be enough?

Let me know if more information is needed!